# Use casting modifier for attack bonus with attack spell action

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack, spellcasting

As an example, [Snowball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/snowball/) is a spell that requires you to make a ranged touch attach.

This attack is the standard d20 + dex.

Is there any feat or something (specifically for Sorcerer if possible) that can allow to make the spell attack with the casting modifier (Int) instead of the normal attack modifier (Str/Dex) ?

Comment: It’s a good question, but you should know that touch AC is usually **very** easy to hit, and Dexterity is a tertiary score for most spellcasters (after casting ability and Con). Optimizers generally consider touch attacks to be optimal because they hit so reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several sources that use a mental ability score modifier for spell attack rolls.

[Magus Arcana: Arcane Accuracy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/paizo-magus-arcana/arcane-accuracy-su) is a limited resource that allows a magus to add their Int modifier to all attack rolls for one round, which includes spell attack rolls. If the magus has the [Eldritch Scion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/eldritch-scion/) archetype, they use their Cha instead of Int for this bonus. However, this bonus is in addition to the Str/Dex modifier that is included in their attack roll modifier.

[Witch hex: Prehensile Hair](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes/hexes/common-hexes/hex-prehensile-hair-su/) is a 10-foot natural weapon that uses Int (instead of Str) for its attack and damage rolls. As a natural weapon, it can be used to deliver touch attacks for spells.

[Guided Hand](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/guided-hand/) is a feat that adds Wis instead of Str/Dex for attack rolls using your deity's favored weapon. Since a natural weapon can be used to deliver touch attacks, you can apply Guided Strike to these attacks if your deity's favored weapon is a natural weapon.

[Smite Evil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Paladin/#TOC-Smite-Evil-Su-), the paladin class feature, adds their Cha modifier to attack rolls versus one creature when this ability is activated. This benefit also applies to spell attacks and could synergize with a Sorcerer multiclass. There are variations in other classes and archetypes (such as [Hellknight](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/hellknight/)'s Smite Chaos, [Antipaladin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Alternate-Classes/antipaladin/#TOC-Smite-Good-Su-)'s Smite Good, or the [Champion of the Faith (Warpriest)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/warpriest/archetypes/paizo-warpriest-archetypes/champion-of-the-faith/)'s Smite) that provide a similar benefit.

This list excludes spells that already use the caster's ability score as part of the attack (e.g. [*Spiritual Weapon*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spiritual-weapon/)).

---

Source: ["Getting X to Y - A Pathfinder guide to using your ability scores
"](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o91Z-s0R7Vf2Ujj1lFqGC5W--9JOyU0I6uC9XRIR5to/) (public Google doc, found as search result for `pathfinder add int to attack`)

Comment: "If your deity's favored weapon is a natural weapon (but not an unarmed strike), then it can be used for touch attacks for spells." Could you cite this? I know of no such rule except GM rulings regarding making a regular attack while holding a Touch spell

Comment: @Ifusaso Thanks for pointing that out. I think my language was not clear. Guided Strike applies to all attacks (not just weapon attacks) made with their deity's favored weapon. Unarmed strikes and manufactured weapons can't make touch attacks, but natural weapons can, therefore a natural weapon can use Guided Strike for spell touch attacks. It should be clearer now.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand, I just don't know of any rule that definitively says that Natural Attacks can deliver Touch Spells beyond the general ruling of Touch spells triggering on touch (which would count for most Unarmed Attacks for most GMs as well); notably, casting a Touch spell allows you to deliver it but not to make a Natural Attack to do so, and making a Natural Attack on a future turn does not target Touch AC

Comment: Furthermore, it is highly unlikely this applies to ranged Touch attacks such as Snowball (although if there is a rule that I'm unaware of, it could be good to note for melee Touch spells)